# Convert List of string to Integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list whose elements are only single string.

```
my_list = ['9', '4', '4', '5', '4', '3', '5']
```

How can I convert this into a single integer like: 9445435

Note: `' '.join()` only works for lists of strings, not integers.

Comment: Use `join` and then cast it to int! like => `int(''.join(my_list))`

Comment: Is your list made of integers or of strings? If integers, then `int(''.join(str(v) for v in my_list))`, otherwise what DarkSuniuM said

Comment: You _say_ it's a list of integers, but the list you have in your question contains **strings**, not integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = ' '.join(my_list)

result = int(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
In [5]: int(''.join(my_list))
Out[5]: 9445435
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this approach?

```
my_list = ['9', '4', '4', '5', '4', '3', '5']
output = int(''.join(str(num) for num in my_list))
print(output) ## 9445435
```

Comment: or `output = int(''.join(my_list))`

Comment: @eyllanesc nah, the `for` is there so if the list items was int, it casts them to str

Comment: @DarkSuniuM `join` accepts an iterable and converts them internally with `str()` to each iterable element, the `for` is unnecessary

Comment: @eyllanesc `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: @DarkSuniuM `my_list = ['9', '4', '4', '5', '4', '3', '5']
output = int(''.join(my_list))
print(output)`  ---> 9445435 in Python 2.7.15 and  python 3.7.1

Comment: @eyllanesc, I said in case the items was `int`, not `str`

Comment: @DarkSuniuM The OP notes that the input is:: `my_list = ['9', '4', '4', '5', '4', '3', '5']`

Comment: @DarkSuniuM What the OP indicates is not correct, it has a list of strings where each string represents a digit

Comment: @eyllanesc So sharing more information is wrong!? or giving a solution that works on both situations is wrong?